# Android: onPause is too late to save editText contents

Tags: android, save, android-edittext, onpause

I want to save the text of an editText view when the user presses the back button. So I call `(EditText)e.getText().toString()` within the `onPause()` procedure. But this is too late: when `onPause()` is being called after pressing the back button, the view is already gone and `e.getText().toString()` freezes the application.

This happens on a Samsung GT-I9000  with firmware 2.1-update1.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call your `e.getText().toString()` before `super.onPause();`

Answer (score 0):

What API level are you working on?

Since API Level 5 you can override the function **[onBackPressed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29)**, if not, you will have to use **[onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29)** method

Comment: Well, I was asking about the API for the app not the specific model you are testing on. :)

Comment: But why is onPause too late? According to the activity lifecycle documentation this overriding of onBackPressed should not be necessary...

Comment: Without seeing the code, that's what I can suggest to check if it's a problem with the lifecycle or it is somewhere else. did you tried it?